# Maple - linear transformation - parametric equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, maple

I have the line
$l = \begin{cases}
x=-2t+1 \\ 
y=3t-2 \\ 
z=t+4
\end{cases}
$
and a linear transformation $T$ and I want to find a parametric equation of the line $l^*$ so that $l^*$ is the image of the line $l$ under $T\\ \\$ $\\$
($T: l\rightarrow l^*\\$)
Is the general approach or function to solve this kind of problem using Maple 18? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your line in the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} l\\m\\n\end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{bmatrix}.$$
The equations you are looking for are the following: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z'\end{bmatrix} = T\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=T\left(\begin{bmatrix} l\\m\\n\end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0\end{bmatrix}\right), $$ 
so you just need to compute a product of the matrix $T$ times a vector, and this can be done with the dot . in the LinearAlgebra package.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really know how this could be done in maple. I tried to write the line in the form of $<-2t+1|3t-2|t+4>$ and then multiply it with my vector $Vector(3, {(1) = -(1/4)*sqrt(3)+1/2, (2) = 1/2+sqrt(3), (3) = -3/4+(1/2)*sqrt(3)})$ but that did not give me the answer I was looking for...

Comment: Sorry, you were correct! I misinterperted the question in my book and used the wrong matrix. Therefore, nothing made sense... Thanks again!